# Reading and understanding MCU datasheet and codes

Tags: microcontroller, specifications, datasheet

Are there any tips for reading source code samples from manufacturer of MCUs'.
I am a newbie for mcu programming, currently I have a MCU, datasheet and sample codes for them. But problem is sample codes are seems written for experienced users. Too many questions about why they initialized RS232, why they set 4th bit of port 1 and etc.,

Do you have a tips for reading or links where can I get info about how to read datasheets and sample codes of MCU?

Comment: if some details are not enough please add them I will rewrite my question relying on your comments

Comment: It would help if you provided a specific example; what uC are you using, and what is the questionable source code.  Then we can help you specifically rather than generally.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot give details of uC and source codes, I just want to know general reading steps of datasheets and codes for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess experience is the only answer I can give.  Just like with programming in general, with time you acquire experience as well as learn buzz words and concepts.  With microcontrollers you learn to read datasheets, schematics, etc.  Learn about open drain, open collector, weak pull ups, etc.  And for serial ports for some reason they are always overcomplicated.  The hardest part with microcontrollers and the serial port is usually figuring out what to program to get the right clock divisors, some microcontroller serial ports are straight forward, others are overly complicated, some docs are good some docs are bad, etc.

Another answer is datasheets are always wrong.  There are always gaps in the information that you have to hack to figure out.  Do not write thousands of lines of code in a vaccuum using only a datasheet, write a small amount of code a few lines to a few dozen, test, and move on, you can get more lines written and debugged in a day when programming from a datasheet than the other path.  The datasheets are often not written by the engineers that actually designed the hardware, sometimes it is a junior engineer or a non-engineer.  Sometimes the information is simply wrong, sometimes the document is for a different but similar part than the one you have.  If they provide software that actually does stuff it is sometimes (not always) more accurate than the datasheet (when I say datasheet assume the users manual, programmers reference manual, whatever the vendor calls the doc with the registers, addressses, and bit definitions for the hardware).

With time and experience you may find, if you take a wide enough view, that some vendors tend to do a better job at providing information to users, others do not, some bury the secrets in libraries, sometimes in binary form and not source.  Sometimes the secrets are buried in compilers and other tools they provide (well that is back to apis and libraries).  I tend to blacklist such companies, but sometimes you cant always.  ARM for example does a very good job of providing the information.  the problem is they have so many cores with a number of options each, that are very similar in nature (support the same instruction sets) that it can be difficult to sort through what the one processor you are using that moment does and does not from the docs.  Atmel, something about atmel that is hard to put a finger on, the docs are generally well above par, but more than that something about atmel makes them popular with the customers.  You will never see an arduino like following, culture, pick a word, with a microchip pic for example.  There are a lot of pic followers but it is not like the atmel world (which was there well before the arduino thing happened).

Another note, you might not understand with a single example program and single datasheet the history of a product, there might be code that has been used for a number of chip generations, and there might for example be a bit that is required by an older chip or newer chip and to share the same code that bit is manipulated.  that bit might make sense looking at one datasheet and no sense looking at another.  this is where hacking comes, in try it without, see what happens.  maybe study other parts in the family that this code is said to support it might make more sense.

google is your friend or whatever favorite search engine, find as much open source code and other items for the particular device or whatever.  At this level hacking is required, I dont use that term in the bad sense, hacking in the sense that you have to try some of the bits documented in the datasheet, see if that actually works, if not then see what it does if possible, look at other source code and see from that if you can figure it out.  Just like there is no perfect car that gets infinite miles per gallon, completely safe, lasts forever, and is inexpensive, there is no perfect chip with the perfect datasheet and sample code.  If you want to work at this software/hardware level you have to get your hands dirty, have to not be afraid to let some smoke out of the chips (there is a finite amount of smoke in a chip if you let even a little bit out it wont work), etc.

If the reason you wont ask specifically about the mcu or register you are working with is because it is closed source products or behind an NDA then you probably have access to the company that makes that product and you should be able to get support from them.  Usually better support than you would get from a company that you dont have to sign an NDA for.  Not that open document, open source companies are bad, just that if the company you buy from is interested in you to the point of showing internally protected information they are interested enough to give you better access to the real engineers that made/know the product.  If this is not the case and you are able to talk about it, dont be afraid to just post a question to SO about the register and bits you are wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code and flow charts in the MCU datasheets are good starting point to initialize a specific peripheral (like RS232).
You just start from there, and track the bit information and what it does, in MCU datasheet.